# Changing the color of a button in SwiftUI based on disabled or not

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a textfield with a send button that's a systemImage arrow. I want the foreground color of the image to change depending on whether the textField is empty or not. (I.e. the button is gray, and it is disabled if the textfield is empty. It's blue if the count of the textfield text is > 1).

I have a workaround that's not perfect:

```swift
if chatMessageIsValid {
    Spacer()
    HStack {
        TextField($chatMessage, placeholder: Text("Reply"))
            .padding(.leading, 10)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        Button(action: sendMessage) {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.up.circle")
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                .padding(.trailing, 10)
        }.disabled(!chatMessageIsValid)
    }
} else {
    Spacer()
    HStack {
        TextField($chatMessage, placeholder: Text("Reply"))
            .padding(.leading, 10)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        Button(action: sendMessage) {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.up.circle")
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                .padding(.trailing, 10)
        }.disabled(!chatMessageIsValid)
    }
}
```

This almost works, and it does change the color of the image if the text is > 1 in length. However, due to the change in state you're kicked out of editing the textfield after one character is typed, and you'll need to select the textfield again to continue typing. Is there a better way to do this with the .disabled modifier?

Comment: Move the button off into its own type (so that the text field doesn't get redrawn when the state changes) and use the `@State`-binding pattern.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I guess you want this:

[image: demo]

You can add a computed property for the button color, and pass the property to the button's `foregroundColor` modifier. You can also use a single `padding` modifier around the `HStack` instead of separate `padding`s on its subviews.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var chatMessage: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField($chatMessage, placeholder: Text("Reply"))
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            Button(action: sendMessage) {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.up.circle")
                    .foregroundColor(buttonColor)
            }
                .disabled(!chatMessageIsValid)
        }
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 10)
    }

    var chatMessageIsValid: Bool {
        return !chatMessage.isEmpty
    }

    var buttonColor: Color {
        return chatMessageIsValid ? .accentColor : .gray
    }

    func sendMessage() {
        chatMessage = ""
    }
}
```

**However**, you shouldn't use the `foregroundColor` modifier at all here. You should use the `accentColor` modifier. Using `accentColor` has two benefits:

- The `Image` will automatically use the environment's `accentColor` when the `Button` is enabled, and gray when the `Button` is disabled. You don't have to compute the color at all.
- You can set the `accentColor` in the environment high up in your `View` hierarchy, and it will trickle down to all descendants. This makes it easy to set a uniform accent color for your whole interface.

In the following example, I put the `accentColor` modifier on the `HStack`. In a real app, you would probably set it on the root view of your entire app:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var chatMessage: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField($chatMessage, placeholder: Text("Reply"))
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            Button(action: sendMessage) {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.up.circle")
            }
                .disabled(!chatMessageIsValid)
        }
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 10)
            .accentColor(.orange)
    }

    var chatMessageIsValid: Bool {
        return !chatMessage.isEmpty
    }

    func sendMessage() {
        chatMessage = ""
    }
}
```

Also, Matt's idea of extracting the send button into its own type is probably smart. It makes it easy to do nifty things like animating it when the user clicks it:

[image: button animation demo]

Here's the code:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var chatMessage: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField($chatMessage, placeholder: Text("Reply"))
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            SendButton(action: sendMessage, isDisabled: chatMessage.isEmpty)
        }
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 10)
            .accentColor(.orange)
    }

    func sendMessage() {
        chatMessage = ""
    }
}

struct SendButton: View {
    let action: () -> ()
    let isDisabled: Bool

    var body: some View {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.action()
                    self.clickCount += 1
                }
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.up.circle")
                    .rotationEffect(.radians(2 * Double.pi * clickCount))
                    .animation(.basic(curve: .easeOut))
            }
                .disabled(isDisabled)
    }

    @State private var clickCount: Double = 0
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. I really like the idea of making the SendButton it's own type. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Awesome! That `accentColor` modifier is a great tip!

Comment: Nice! But if I also set the foreground color, that color overrides the accentColor. So, how can I combine accentColor(.orange) with a foregroundColor(.secondary)  on the ordinary text?

Answer (score 39):

With these various solutions, you can use the `\.isEnabled` environment property instead of creating custom button styles or passing in disabled booleans yourself.

```
@Environment(\.isEnabled) private var isEnabled
```

Answer (score 16):

If you want to customize the button even further with disabled (or any other) state, you can add variables to your custom ButtonStyle struct.

**Swift 5.1**

```
struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    var disabled = false
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
        .background(disabled ? .red : .blue)
    }
}

// SwiftUI
@State var isDisabled = true
var body: some View {
    Button().buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle(disabled: self.isDisabled))
}
```

Comment: NIce answer! You could also add a dot syntax extension to that button style to do `Button().buttonStyle(.disabled(self.isDisabled))`

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
Spacer()
HStack {
    TextField($chatMessage, placeholder: Text("Reply"))
        .padding(.leading, 10)
        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
    Button(action: sendMessage) {
        Image(systemName: "arrow.up.circle")
            .foregroundColor(chatMessageIsValid ? Color.blue : Color.gray)
            .padding(.trailing, 10)
        }.disabled(!chatMessageIsValid)
}
```

I suppose, the reason `TextField` loses focus is that in your code the whole view hierarchy is changed depending on the value of `chatMessageIsValid`. SwiftUI doesn't understand that the view hierarchy in the `then` block is almost identical to the one in the `else` block, so it rebuilds it completely.

In this edited code it should see that the only thing that changes is the `foregroundColor` of the image and the `disabled` status of the button, leaving the `TextField` untouched. Apple had a similar examples in one of the WWDC videos, I believe.

Answer (score 4):

All modifier arguments can be conditional:

```
.foregroundColor(condition ? .red : .yellow)
```

where the condition could be any `true`/`false`

```
var condition: Bool { chatMessage.isEmpty } // can be used inline
```

<sub>You can use any other condition you need</sub>